# Cordova: Adaptive icon shows foreground image, but not background colour

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I have a cordova project, and I have used the Android Studio image wizard to make an adaptive icon by using an image as the foreground and a drawable colour as the background. I have done this before and it works fine, but for this particular project the background colour does not display, either in the simulator or on device. The foreground image however displays correctly. Even stranger, the preview view that shows when I open the ic_launcher.xml file shows the icon correctly, with both foreground image and background colour displayed.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="30000" android:versionName="3.0" package="io.custom.fit" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
</manifest>
```

and my ic_launcher.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

got a color.xml file too:

```
<resources>
    <color name="ic_launcher_background">#6EADEA</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the foreground image has a transparent background. I had this problem and spent way to much time debugging it before I realized that the foreground image was incorrectly exported and had a grayish background color, so it covered the background icon in Android.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with cordova v10.0.0. My foreground images have transparent background color and the background images are still not visible. Did anybody found a solution?

Comment: I'm having same issue on cordova v10.0.0